# What encoding are the LPCWSTR strings expected to be when calling the API?

Tags: winapi, unicode

I am trying to call the `MessageBoxW` Windows API function through the FFI of an esoteric language.

I have two strings to provide to the function. I may be wrong, but I understand that the `LPCWSTR` pointer is supposed to point to a null-terminated string of `wchar_t` (the width of which is compiler-specific)

What are the expected character set and encoding of these strings in the Win32 API?

Comment: LPCWSTR is a type alias for `const wchar_t*`.  Always utf-16, not compiler specific for any compiler that can use the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required encoding is Unicode UTF-16LE.

Whilst the size of `wchar_t` is implementation defined, on Windows `wchar_t` is always 16 bit.

Comment: UTF-16 **LE** the endianness matters in this particular case

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, maybe you could include this in your answer?

Comment: OK, I did that. I kind of took that for granted though because Windows only runs on little endian platforms. If one day it ran on big endian then it would use UTF-16BE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in fact (parts of) the NT kernel have been ported to PPC-BE for Xbox360, and they do use UTF-16BE there.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky What about NT on Alpha? Was that BE?

Comment: No, Alpha was LE, as was the original NT for PPC.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you. I just wanted to make the answer more complete with regards to the FFI.